# STM32 difference in debugging

Tags: stm32

I have an accelerometer connected to a NUCLEO for test, connected with normal cables. I2C communication.
The strange thing I notice, it doesn't always happen, when I shake the accelerometer in debug mode following the code line by line it prints the data. If I don't set any breakpoints and start debugging in run mode and shake the accelerometer I don't see any printed data. Has anyone had a similar experience or know what could be the cause of not printing data?

Comment: _what could be the cause of not printing data_ Bug in your software? We don't know anything about what do you do, how are we expected to help?

Comment: I suspect it's something with the timings. When you go line by line, you give the peripherals time to shift out the data or something of this sort. Try adding artificial delays after function calls that send data, see if anything changes. How is your print implemented? Blocking? Interrupts? DMA? Does it actually send nothing or a bunch of null characters (that won't show up at all in basic terminal programs)? Do peripherals have any flags set, like overrun in UART? Collect some info.

Comment: @Ilya: Thank you. I have the same accelerometer with the same configuration in a Nordic micro board and everything works correctly there. Here when I use simple printfs to print data I get this strange behavior which doesn't always happen. Then I'll try the suggestions you gave me